# Metadata de Tipos en Funciones Anónimas en Clojure

Tags: clojure

Estoy creando una pequeña aplicación para aprender Clojure y acabo de habilitar la bandera que advierte de aquellos casos en donde se está incurriendo en "Java reflection" en mi código, algo que idealmente se puede mejorar por medio de agregar anotaciones de tipos en mis funciones y así mejorar el desempeño.

Sin embargo, he encontrado que algunos de los casos reportados por el compilador provienen de lugares en donde uso funciones de orden superior o en donde he usado la notación especial para declarar funciones anónimas y no se me ocurre una manera sencilla de anotar esas funciones sin tener que expandirlas o encapsular su llamado en otras funciones.

Por ejemplo, consideren el siguiente código:

```
(deftest test-java-expenses
    (testing "Testing Expenses"
        (let [total-cents (map (memfn amountInCents) expenses)]
            (is (= 7406 (apply + total-cents))))))
```

Donde `expenses` es un vector que contiene objetos de un tipo/clase llamado `Expense`.

Parece que la queja del compilador es sobre la llamada a `amountInCents`, Clojure usa "Java reflection" sobre los arguments para determinar su tipo (p.ej. `Expense` en este caso).

Puedo deshacerse de la advertencia por medio de cambiar `(memfn amountInCents)` por `(fn [^Expense e] (.amountInCents e))` pero esto hace mi código más difícil de leer y, en mi opinión, es menos elegante.

Tendría el mismo problema si cambio mi código para usar una función anónima declarada de la siguiente manera: `#(.amountInCents %)`

Incluso consideré crear una función para crear los objetos `Expense` y cuyo tipo de retorno estuviera anotado esperando que el compilador pudiera inferir los tipos luego, algo así:

```cli
(defn new-expense ^Expense [date-string dollars cents category merchant-name]
    (Expense. date-string dollars cents category merchant-name))
```

Y entonces crear los objetos `Expense` haciendo algo como:

```cli
(def expenses [(new-expense "2009-8-24" 44 95 "books" "amazon.com")
               (new-expense "2009-8-25" 29 11 "gas" "shell")])
```

Pero esto tampoco funcionó; el compilador aún no puede inferir que el vector en cuestión es un vector de objetos `Expense`, y la advertencia de "Java reflection" permanece.

¿Existe alguna forma de agregar metadata de tipos a mis funciones para casos como los mencionados arriba en donde uso una función anónima declarada como `#()`, o cuando uso funciones de order superior (p.ej. `memfn`)?

Es decir, ¿existe una una manera de hacerlo sin tener que expandir yo mismo la declaración de mis funciones (p.ej. `(fn [^Type n] ....)`?

Answer (score 2):

Recibí [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34374998/697630) de [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt) a esta pregunta en Stackoverflow en inglés.

¿Sólo necesitas agregar un "type hint" a tu llamada a `memfn`?

Ver la documentación de [`memfn` docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memfn) (donde `memfn` se describe como `(memfn name & args)`):

> `name` puede ser enriquecido con el tipo del método receptor para evitar llamas con reflexión.

Así que en tu caso puedes hacer algo como:

```
(memfn ^Expense amountInCents)
```

para evitar el uso de reflexión.

Answer (score 1):

La funcion que necesita `metadata` es la que recive cada uno de los `expenses`, en este caso la funcion anonima que se pasa a `map` ya que es la que hace uso de `amountInCents` y debe resolver `expenses` el tipo de dato apropiado en base a refleccion. Las anotaciones como `^Expense` tambien son `metadata` especial para ayudar con type hints.

Ademas

Asi que basicamente solo tienes la opcion de usar `^Expense`, la cual se advierte usar solo en casos de desempeño importantes segun la documentacion de [clojure](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints)

Comment: Si te refieres a `(fn [^Expense e] (.amountInCents e))`, eso es precisamente lo que estoy tratando de evitar, según explico en la pregunta. Sin embargo, si tienes un ejemplo que no requiera la expansión de la función de orden superior, eso es lo que estoy buscando.

Comment: Ya lo se, en la respuesta explico el porque es inevitable usar la anotacion en la funcion anonima, pues es esta la que recive `expenses`, no importa que hayas declarado varibles o parametros con `^Expenses` fuera de este codigo. La respuesta seria que no existe tal forma de omitir la anotacion y deshacerse de la refleccion.